# IntelliJ connection to Cassandra using kerberos

Tags: intellij-idea, cassandra, kerberos

Is there a way to connect to Cassandra with Kerberos using IntelliJ? If not, is there any other IDE that provides this feature?

Comment: Also, take a look at the article [Kerberos Authenticator for Apache Cassandra](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-the-kerberos-authenticator-for-apache)

Comment: Yes, I've seen this and am aware of how to use it in a Java application, but I'd like a Cassandra IDE where I can connect using Kerberos. It'll be great not to have to write a custom tool to query tables while experimenting or debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Datagrip only supports SSL authentication method in Apache Cassandra. For this reason, we have created a feature request:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16789/

Feel free to upvote so it can get more attention.